# Android GridView press two elements

Tags: android, gridview

I have a `GridView` as to detect depression in two adjacent cells? And thus that these cells were near or just horizontally, or just in the vertical direction. Sorry for my English. I will accept any help to do it. Using `GridView` is not necessarily

[image]